# Show image from datagridview when selectionchange

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I have a datagridview with a datasource MS Access, I use Ole Object data type. The data are shown in the datagridview, But I want the image to be placed in the picturebox when I click on a row/ item, 
I tried this code, but nothing happens

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                pictureBox2.Image = (Image)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Picture"].Value;
            }
        }
```

Can you help me with this? thanks.

Comment: I also tried this code, but it does not show also `pictureBox2.ImageLocation = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Picture"].Value.ToString();`

Comment: what are you binding in that `"Picture"` column ? a `byte[]` containing image bytes or a path to the image location ?

Comment: @yogi a byte[], do i need to convert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["Picture"].Value);
                pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
```